# building gcc 7 (head) from repository on macos sierra?

Tags: c++, gcc, configure, macos-sierra

I have homebrew gcc 6 installed, but would like to play with gcc 7 on my mac running sierra. However, instead of the simple configure make that worked in the past, things have changed so much with sierra that I no longer can figure out, how to get gcc compiling itself. I understand that what I checked out from the repo is not supposed to work, but at least I should be able to compile it. The current roadblock is that there is no longer a /usr/include with the system headers and I didn't find the option to point configure/make to use the XCode.app internal one that apperently my homebrew gcc6 knows about.

What is the option to provide to configure to set the directory for system includes (and may be libraries) to get a current gcc compile on macos Sierra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the "Xcode command line tools" from the app store.

That installs an assembler and linker, and the headers in `/usr/include/`, and then the GCC build works as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had those installed, but upgrading the OS to sierra got rid of them. Homebrew seems to be able to got directly into Xcode.app and pull the stuff from there. Apple seems to be unable to trust/set (symbolic) links to keep stuff installed only once, especially with their ridiculous prices for SDDs.